# can't set border radius on one side and border on one side flutter

Tags: flutter, border, border-radius

Why this code hides the child of the container and how to solve this problem.
I can't set border radius on one side and border on one side or two sides

```
Container(
          child: Text(
            "Test",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
              fontFamily: "GE",
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 100.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100.0, horizontal: 100.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[800],
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
            ),
            border: Border(
              top:
                  BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade600),
              bottom:
                  BorderSide(width: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the vertical padding is the same height as the container which leaves no space for the text to show up.

You either need to reduce the padding or increase the container height.

=== update based on the comment:

You cannot add both `border` and `borderRadius` together, hence you're getting the error.

Since it appears that you only want to add a color at the bottom and the top, you can instead use a `boxShadow` with `borderRadius`:

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.grey[800],
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
    bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
  ),
  boxShadow: [
    BoxShadow(color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900, spreadRadius: 3),
  ],
),
```

If you want to have a different Color at the top than the bottom, you have to work around that. One way you can do the trick is to offset the shadow so it acts as a bottom border color only. Then wrap the Container in a Column, and add another thin Container above it to act as the top border color such as:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    // top border color
    Container(
      height: 5.0,
      color: Colors.lightBlue.shade600,
    ),
    Container(
      child: Text(
        "Test",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
          fontFamily: "GE",
          fontSize: 30.0,
        ),
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 100.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[800],
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900,
            spreadRadius: 3,
            // offset to act as bottom border color
            offset: Offset(0, 5),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I removed padding, but actually the problem like I said
when I removed the border radius it solved
so, the problem in the combination of border radius one side and border in one or two sides

Comment: @ĀĥmêdŴǻlêd Are you getting any error message in the debug console? If so, post them in the question.

Comment: Exception caught by rendering library
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border.

The following is not uniform:
BorderSide.color
BorderSide.width
BorderSide.style
The relevant error-causing widget was
Container
lib\widgets\header.dart:8
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Border.paint.<anonymous closure>
#1      Border.paint
#2      _BoxDecorationPainter.paint
#3      RenderDecoratedBox.paint

#4      RenderObject._paintWithContext

Comment: The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderDecoratedBox#d5c3f
RenderObject: RenderDecoratedBox#d5c3f
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=480.0, h=100.0)
    size: Size(480.0, 100.0)
    decoration: BoxDecoration
        color: Color(0xff424242)
        border: Border(top: BorderSide(Color(0xff039be5), 16.0, BorderStyle.solid), bottom: BorderSide(Color(0xff01579b), 16.0, BorderStyle.solid))
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50.0))

Comment: configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#913ef(), devicePixelRatio: 1.0, locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
    child: RenderPadding#763ac NEEDS-PAINT
        parentData: <none> (can use size)
        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=480.0, h=100.0)

Comment: I'm sorry for dividing the error as the comment has limit

Comment: @ĀĥmêdŴǻlêd I updated my answer. By the way, you can always edit your question to add more info instead of using the comment since it's limited.